# Process http get request completely before click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following javascript code:-

```
$scope.fav_bill_details=function (id1,id2,bill_id) {
document.getElementById(id2).style.display="none";
$scope.getActiveBill();
document.getElementById(id1).style.display="block";
$scope.getBillDetails(bill_id);
$timeout(function(){
    var btn=angular.element(document.getElementById(bill_id));
    angular.element(document.getElementById(btn.id)).trigger('click');
    });
};
```

As you can see from above there are two function call above:- `$scope.getActiveBill();` and `$scope.getBillDetails(bill_id);`, both of these functions has http get requests. They get the data and process it and store it in $scope variables. What I want is these request to be completed before I trigger the click event as above. I have implemented promises in both function. But the click even finishes first and then the http requests are completed. How can I achieve the above requirement??

Comment: You should add the definitions of the functions `getActiveBill` and `getBillDetails`. The key is to register function that triggers click to be executed when there is a response. You will be able to do it by manipulating those two functions that make the requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the promises, like this:

```
$scope.fav_bill_details=function (id1,id2,bill_id) {
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display="none";
    $scope.getActiveBill().then(function() {
        document.getElementById(id1).style.display="block";
        return $scope.getBillDetails(bill_id);
    }).then(function () {
        var btn=angular.element(document.getElementById(bill_id));                   
        angular.element(document.getElementById(btn.id)).trigger('click');
    });
```

In your example you call asynchronous functions but don't wait for them to finish, this solves it.

Comment: but does the function `getActiveBill` return a promise object. Also are you sure this will wait for `getBillDetails` to complete the request? I think `getBillDetails` should also return a promise object and `then` should be run on that like this:

    `return $scope.getBillDetails(bill_id).then(function () { /*trigger thingy*/
    });`

Comment: Firstly he wrote they both return promises. And what yu suggest is what I wrote, when a promise returns another promise then it waits for the next promise too. so what I wrote is getActiveBill =(wait-for-promise)=> getBillDetails =(wait-for-promise)=> do stuff

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, I didn't see him mentioning promises. Also you are right about how promises will work. I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: @Nayish The function doesnot return any promises...I said the function has promises because sometimes those functions are called at different times so for that I implemented promises in them so that I process the data only after I get all values...Can we do some some new promises in this function like wait for both function to finish their http calls.

Comment: No, you simply need those functions to return there promises.
Promises are asynchronous so you can't know when they are done unless you use callbacks/promises (or async await in ES6)